# La validación de la hora mínima de un input datetime-local no funciona

Tags: html, validación, datetime, input, input-type

Tengo un input type="datetime-local" al que le estoy estableciendo una fecha y hora mínima (en el snippet pongo solo los atributos relevantes para la validación):

```html
<input
   type="datetime-local"
   min="2021-11-09T02:00:00"
   required>
```

Probando de esta forma y mirando [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) y ejemplos de otras preguntas, no he llegado a conseguir que si selecciono el día 9/11/2021, se me deshabiliten las horas previas a las 02:00.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe si alguna una forma de hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te deje una posible solución con JS además.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> min
>
> The earliest date and time to accept; timestamps earlier than this will cause the element to fail constraint validation. If the value of the min attribute isn't a valid string which follows the format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm, then the element has no minimum value.
>
> This value must specify a date string earlier than or equal to the one specified by the max attribute.

En la documentación menciona:

- La fecha mínima a aceptar
- Fechas anteriores a esa, harán que la validación falle
- Si el formato del atributo no es el correcto, entonces el elemento no tiene valor min
- El min debe ser menor o igual al max.

Por lo que **Lo realizado es correcto, pero causará un error al momento de validar**

---

Una forma de poder hacerlo, es con el uso de Javascript.

En este ejemplo, te dejo el uso de la validacion con respecto a la fecha actual. **NO PUEDE SER MENOR O IGUAL A LA ACTUAL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ir acomodandolo a tu gusto.

```js
function TDate() {
var UserDate = document.getElementById("userdate").value;
var ToDate = new Date();
console.log(ToDate.toISOString());
if (new Date(UserDate).toISOString() <= ToDate.toISOString()) {
    alert("La fecha debe ser mayor a (actual): " + ToDate);
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="datetime-local" name="StartDate" id="userdate" onchange="TDate()" required />
</body>
</html>
```